# How to add or update a list in clojure?

Tags: clojure

I've this function and I don't know how to implement it. I only know how to use concat, but it's wrong because it only adds and I also need to update.

Can anyone help me?

**This is the function:**

```
(defn update-env 
  [env-global key value]
  (if (and (list? value) (= (first value) '*error*))
    env-global
    (concat env-global (list key value))))
```

**This is the code I need to run:**
(update-env '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2) 'x 3)

**This is the result it should give:**
(+ add - sub x 3 y 2)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the trick is to operate on collection's elements pairwise something alike the common lisp's `plist`. You can make up something like this:

```
(defn plist-assoc [key new-val plist]
  (->> plist
       (partition 2)
       (mapcat (fn [[k v]] [k (if (= k key) new-val v)]))))

user> (plist-assoc 'x 3 '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2))
;;=> (+ add - sub x 3 y 2)

user> (plist-assoc 'z 3 '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2))
;;=> (+ add - sub x 1 y 2)
```

so than your function looks like this:

```
(defn update-env [env-global key value]
  (if (and (list? value) (= (first value) '*error*))
    env-global
    (plist-assoc key value env-global)))

user> (update-env '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2) 'x 3)
;;=> (+ add - sub x 3 y 2)
```

**update**
if you need to update or insert new value, you can use something like this instead:

```
(defn assoc-plist2 [key new-val plist]
  (let [[l r] (->> plist
                   (partition 2)
                   (split-with (comp nil? #{key} first)))]
    (apply concat `(~@l ~[key new-val] ~@(rest r)))))

user> (assoc-plist2 'x 10 '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2))
;;=> (+ add - sub x 10 y 2)

user> (assoc-plist2 'z 10 '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2))
;;=> (+ add - sub x 1 y 2 z 10)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't add new pair- `(update-env '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2) 'z 3)` returns the same env.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent `env-global` as hash-map and use [`assoc`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/assoc) for update:

```
(defn update-env [env-global key value]
  (if (and (list? value)
           (= (first value) '*error*))
    env-global
    (assoc env-global key value)))

(update-env '{+ add - sub x 1 y 2} 'x 3)
```

Or you can use list and convert it to hash-map and back (**edited**):

```
(defn env->map [env]
  (apply hash-map env))

(defn map->env [m]
  (->> m
       (apply list)
       (apply concat)))

(-> (env->map '(+ add - sub x 1 y 2))
    (update-env 'x 3)
    (map->env))
```

Comment: `flatten` is a ticking time bomb in pretty much all cases. What if your environment is `{x (a b c)}`, for example? You'd accidentally produce `(x a b c)` instead of `(x (a b c))`. Instead use something like `apply concat`.